# How do I root a Zte Origin from Solavei?

Tags: rooting

I got a Zte Origin (solavei service) from [vx4gwireless](http://www.vx4gwireless.com/)

There's a customer in their affiliate program and she's added all these apps and needs to root her phone (and I need to as well). I do not see a Zte Origin in your list of Androids in the [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) section.

Can you please add this phone and instructions on how to root it?

Its the blue Zte Origin, Model number Zte V768 Android version 2.3.7

And I need to know how to delete apps and move them to SD card after rooting!

Thanking you and that I hope someone can help!

Comment: Am sorry! But, this Zte Handset is extremely localized to your country and cannot find the means to enclose instructions on rooting, but however, try using [SuperOneClick](http://shortfuse.org/) toolkit to attempt rooting. And then you can add that to the community page (no reps needed - iirc)

Answer (score 1):

I rooted mine with no trouble. It's been a while but I now have SuperSU and Uninstall on my unit.  I don't remember specifically downloading either one they nay have downloaded along with an 'install'.  So do dome DD and try downloading these two. I do remember I had to fiddle some on the connection between my PC and the ZTE but eventually the rooting software loaded. I also installed Internet Booster, Ram Booster, SDCard Booster and I believe these are by the same software designer and seem to be flawless. These products working together have dramatically speeded up my ZTE Origin and I rarely get 'out of space' warnings - theyare fantastic and I would HIGHLY recommend them.

After getting all of these installed I was able to move a number of apps to my SD card freeing up a ton of space.